# 'query' does not exist in type 'QueryFn' | angularfire2

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular-cli, angularfire2

Argument of type '{ query: { limitTolast: number; orderByKey: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not exist in type 'QueryFn'.

package.json

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
"firebase": "^4.5.1",
```

chat.service.ts

```
getMessages(): FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.db.list('messages', {
      query: { limitTolast : 25, orderByKey: true}
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi Kendi, Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: This problem due to the Angular fire base depreciated Angularfire2 for that add this code it will work import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

Comment: you need to change `firebaseListObservable to AngularFireList`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not working, because AngularFire expects a function to be passed as a second argument.

I think your example was the right way to go during the beta version. (not 100% sure)

You have use it the following way:

```
// make sure to provide a child in the orderByChild call
getMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.db.list('/messages', ref => {
      return ref.limitTolast(25).orderByKey(true)
    });
  }
```

Learn more about querying lists here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Comment: Hi Orlandster, FirebaseListObservable is removed in the AngularFire 5.0. So i cant import FirebaseListObservable .

Comment: @Rijo thanks for the hint. I was not aware of this. I've accepted the review, does it work like this?

Comment: You need to return that inner query as well because it won't accept a void method. You need to do `return ref.limitTolast(25).orderByKey(true)`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking it seems object converted to functions

Answer (score 3):

QueryFn must return a firebase.database.Query, not void.
You can code the query like this one, for more clear:

```
getMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.db.list('/messages', ref => {
      let q = ref.limitTolast(25).orderByKey(true);
      return q;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Don't you have to call `.valueChanges()` on that result for it to return Observable<ChatMessage[]>?

Answer (score 0):

This will work perfectly. Tried by me

```
getMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.db.list('/messages', ref => 
      let q = ref.limitTolast(25).orderByKey(true);
      return q;
    );
  }
```

for more information related to queries goto this link: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
return this.db.list('/categories', ref => ref.orderByChild('name')).valueChanges();
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

due to update on Angular Fire, replace FirebaseListObservable to AngularFireList and make sure you return firebase.database.Query like this

```js
 getMessages(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.db.list('messages', ref => {
      return ref.limitToLast(25).orderByKey();
    });
  }
```