# I am getting error While sending data to the firebase Database in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am working on Angular-firebase based chat Application ,

- I am getting error when I send data to my Angular service file  chat.service.ts
- I am putting error which I am getting below

> ChatFormComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: queryFn is not a function
>           at AngularFireDatabase.push../node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.js.AngularFireDatabase.list
>   (database.js:18)
>           at ChatService.push../src/app/services/chat.service.ts.ChatService.getMessages
>   (chat.service.ts:39)
>           at ChatService.push../src/app/services/chat.service.ts.ChatService.sendMessage
>   (chat.service.ts:29)

- I am putting code of the component which send data to the service file below

.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-form',
  templateUrl: './chat-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-form.component.css']
})
export class ChatFormComponent implements OnInit {

message: string;

  constructor( private _chat: ChatService) {}

  send() {
    console.log(this.message);
    this._chat.sendMessage(this.message);
    this.message = '';
  }
}
```

.html file

```
<input class="chatInput" [(ngModel)]="message"/>

<button class="chatButton"  (click)=send()>Send</button>
```

- the above component code sends data to the service which Interact to the firebase

service code ->

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { ChatMessage } from '../models/chat-message.model';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {

  user: firebase.User;
  chatMessages: FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]>;
  chatMessage: ChatMessage;
  userName: Observable<string>;

  constructor( private db: AngularFireDatabase , private afAuth: AngularFireAuth ) { }

getUser() {}

  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    const timestamp = this.getTimeStamp();
    const email =  'biky700@gmail.com';
    this.chatMessages = this.getMessages();
    this.chatMessages.push({
      message: msg,
      timeSent: timestamp,
      userName:  'Anurag Ranjan',
      email: email });
  }

  getMessages(): FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]> {
    // query to create our message feed binding
    return this.db.list('messages', {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 25,
        orderByKey:  true
      }
    });
  }

  getTimeStamp(){}
 }
}
```

---

### ***Important***

- In the above Service code you can see some part of code which create our message feed binding , code given below

> ```
> getMessages(): FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]> {
>     return this.db.list('messages', {
>       query: {
>         limitToLast: 25,
>         orderByKey:  true
>       }
>     });
>   }
> ```

When I hover on this I am getting a meassage given below

**

> [ts] Argument of type '{ query: { limitToLast: number; orderByKey:
>   boolean; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not
>   exist in type 'QueryFn'. (property) orderByKey: boolean

**

Answer (score 0):

someone seems to have the same problem as yours, it has been answered in this post: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781760/query-does-not-exist-in-type-queryfn-angularfire2).

please try this:

```
getMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
return this.db.list('/messages', ref => {
  ref.limitTolast(25).orderByKey(true)
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You getMessage function should be something like this.

```
getMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.db.list('/messages', ref => 
      let q = ref.limitTolast(25).orderByKey(true);
      return q;
    );
  }
```

For more info, please see this.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md